# How can I fetch "partial matches" with mysql?

Tags: mysql

I need to find best matches from a mysql table given a set of attributes.

For example, given ATTRIBUTE1, ATTRIBUTE2 and ATTRIBUTE3, I want to get the results as follows:

1. rows with all attributes matched
2. rows with 2 attributes matched
3. rows with 1 attribute matched

so far I only know how to accomplish the first statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Users 
WHERE ATTRIBUTE1="aValue", ATTRIBUTE2="aValue", ATTRIBUTE3="aValue" 
LIMIT 20
```

N.B. I need 2 lists. A list with fully matching rows and a list with partial matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can consider to build an composite index in ATTRIBUTE{1..3}

this will benefits for **List A**

```
SELECT *
FROM Users 
WHERE ATTRIBUTE1="aValue" AND ATTRIBUTE2="aValue" AND ATTRIBUTE3="aValue"
LIMIT 20
```

and might help some row in **List B**

```
SELECT *, 
IF (ATTRIBUTE1="aValue", 1, 0) as a1, 
IF (ATTRIBUTE2="aValue", 1, 0) as a2, 
IF (ATTRIBUTE3="aValue", 1, 0) as a3
FROM Users 
WHERE ATTRIBUTE1="aValue" OR ATTRIBUTE2="aValue" OR ATTRIBUTE3="aValue" 
ORDER BY (a1+a2+a3) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: I'm not going to have a huge dataset.. probably hundreds of rows.. but it could be thousands. What would be a good solution then ? And why do you suggest me a solution giving very bad performance ?

Comment: mhm, Is there a way to get 2 separate results list. A first list with the users satisfying all requirements and a second list with partial matches ?

Comment: MySQL can sometimes use the indexes (like here, if they exist in the 3 Attributes) to optimize such queries using Index-Merge (Union Access algorithm): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-merge-optimization.html#index-merge-union